# plotly colormap addition to the chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
colorscale='Earth'
#print("     :  Min  :   Q1   : Median :   Q3   :    Max  :  Mean  : Good Mean : Good STD : Outliers :")
data = [
    {
        'x': ['Min','Min','Min','Min','Min'],
        'y': ['config1','config2','config3','config4','config5'],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'marker': {
            'color': [0.89,0.892,0.886,0.901,0.869],
            'size': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
            'showscale': False,
            'colorscale':colorscale,
            'reversescale':True,
            'cmin':0.865,
            'cmax':0.901,
        }
    },
    {
        'x': ['Q1','Q1','Q1','Q1','Q1'],
        'y': ['config1','config2','config3','config4','config5'],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'marker': {
            'color': [0.912,0.908,0.892,0.915,0.889],
            'size': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
            'showscale': False, 
            'colorscale':colorscale,
            'reversescale':True,
            'cmin':0.885,
            'cmax':0.915,
        }
    },
    {
        'x': ['Median','Median','Median','Median','Median'],
        'y': ['config1','config2','config3','config4','config5'],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'marker': {
            'color': [0.919,0.912,0.914,0.917,0.9],
            'size': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
            'showscale': False,
            'colorscale':colorscale,
            'reversescale':True,
            'cmin':0.89,
            'cmax':0.919,
        }
    },
    {
        'x': ['Q3','Q3','Q3','Q3','Q3'],
        'y': ['config1','config2','config3','config4','config5'],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'marker': {
            'color': [0.929,0.919,0.925,0.922,0.909],
            'size': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
            'showscale': False,
            'colorscale':colorscale,
            'reversescale':True,
            'cmin':0.90,
            'cmax':0.929,
        }
    },
    {
        'x': ['Max','Max','Max','Max','Max'],
        'y': ['config1','config2','config3','config4','config5'],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'marker': {
            'color': [0.95,0.932,0.933,0.935,0.935],
            'size': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
            'showscale': False, 
            'colorscale':colorscale,
            'reversescale':True,
            'cmin':0.93,
            'cmax':0.95,
        }
    },
    {
        'x': ['Mean','Mean','Mean','Mean','Mean'],
        'y': ['config1','config2','config3','config4','config5'],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'marker': {
            'color': [0.921,0.912,0.91,0.918,0.9],
            'size': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
            'showscale': False, 
            'colorscale':colorscale,
            'reversescale':True,
            'cmin':0.898,
            'cmax':0.921,
        }
    }
]
layout = go.Layout(title='Parameters of evaluation', xaxis=dict(range=[-0.5, 10]), yaxis=dict(range=[-0.5, 5.5]))
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)                           

#plotly.offline.iplot(data, filename='scatter-colorscale')
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Hello all i am working on a visualization, just started with plotly today, it is so cool. Anyways, I wish to add colormap at the side of the diagram, for what ever color scheme I chose, for me it is probably impossible to find a global colormap because my color gradient start and end points are different. But how can I at least add a colormap at the side which show which is highest color and what is the lowest color. Is there a easy way?

[I want to add colormap like this, at right hand side](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/colors-and-colormaps/)

[image: The output image i have right now looks like this, apart from the trace and title etc which I have to remove later, somehow.]
[image: I wanted to do this, in a proper way]

Comment: Something like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlIVA.png Setting `cmin` and `cmax` manually will make it difficult to have one unified colorscale.

Comment: Added a hacky solution output. I added a extra trace with opacity zero and added a custom color bad to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
        'x': ['Mean','Mean','Mean','Mean','Mean'],
        'y': ['config1','config2','config3','config4','config5'],
        'mode': 'markers,text',
        'marker': {
            'colorbar':dict(nticks=3,tickmode='array',tickvals=[2,4.5,7],showticklabels=True,ticktext=['lowest','middle','highest']),
            'size': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
            'showscale': True, 
            'colorscale':colorscale,
            'reversescale':True,
            'opacity':0
        }

    }
```

I added one of the hack like this, to solve my problem for now. Others can suggest me better way to do it. I added a extra trace with opacity zero and added a custom colorbar to it. It enabled me to add a colorbar which does not mess with other data. I could have added this colorbar in any of the trace too.